# Webmatrix - Saving paragraphs in database

Tags: razor, webmatrix

i have a page where users can type some data into a text field. If i type a few paragraphs in this text filed, it saves to the database fine, but it doesn't save where the paragraphs are, so it returns it as one big block of text. How do i get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you accept text from a textarea, line breaks are stored as the non-visible \n character. When you render the text back to the browser, you need ot replace those \n characters with something that HTML understands, i.e. `<br />` tags:

```
@Html.Raw(myTextAreaContent.Replace("\n", "<br />"))
```

The Html.Raw helper is required if you do not want HTML to be encoded for display, but to be treated as HTML.